# How to generate multiple rows conditioned on the current rows using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame containing multiple 4 digit codes. Based on the value of the third digit I would like to manipulate the data frame in the following way:

1. If 3rd digit != "0" do nothing
2. If 3rd digit == "0" then eliminate this element and replace it with the following one **xx{10-99}**. Where xx are the initial fist two digits of the element and {10-99} indicates {xx10,xx11,xx12,...,xx99} should be added to the data frame.

Any ideas how this could be implemented maybe with dplyr?
Thanks in advance!

e.g.

```r
df <- data.frame("id"= c("1111","1231","1000","2222","2900")
df
```

and i would like to convert df to the following df

```r
{"1111","1231","1010","1011",...,"1099","2222","2910","2911",..."2999"}
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for starting with some sample data, DimitrisPassas. Some thoughts: (1) `print(df)` is extraneous without its output, and even with that I don't think it adds anything (since `df` is really self-evident); (2) you fixed it, but please don't add highlights to the raw data that will corrupt the patterns we're looking for. That is, `"10**00**"` defeats the "third character" comparisons, and requires that we manually edit the sample data. The fix is more usable. The output is suggestive and just clear enough, often "expected output" is in the correct R `class`, such as a truncated frame. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble(id = 1:2, code = c("1111", "2201"))
dat
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#      id code 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 1111 
# 2     2 2201 

dat %>%
  filter(substr(code, 3, 3) == "0") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do({
    newcodes <- sprintf("%02i", 0:3)
    mutate(as_tibble(.)[rep(1, length(newcodes)),],
           code = paste0(substr(code, 1, 2), newcodes))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(dat, substr(code, 3, 3) != "0"), .)
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#      id code 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 1111 
# 2     2 2200 
# 3     2 2201 
# 4     2 2202 
# 5     2 2203
```

I went from 00 to 03, you can fill it out to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach using `tidyr::uncount`

```r
df <- data.frame("id" = c("1111","1231","1000","2222","2900"))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% uncount(ifelse(substr(id, 3, 3) == '0', 90, 1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(substr(id, 3, 3) == '0', 
                        paste0(substr(id, 1, 2), row_number() + 9), 
                        id)) %>%
  ungroup
#> # A tibble: 183 x 1
#>    id   
#>    <chr>
#>  1 1111 
#>  2 1231 
#>  3 1010 
#>  4 1011 
#>  5 1012 
#>  6 1013 
#>  7 1014 
#>  8 1015 
#>  9 1016 
#> 10 1017 
#> # ... with 173 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>